# Populating a parameter in SSRS 2014 report from URL

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2014

I have researched the heck out of this and as far as I can tell I am doing it correctly. I have created a report called Traveler using visual studio and deployed it. The report comes up but asks for a parameter even though I have included the parameter in the URL. `http://crvsql01/Reports_MADE2MANAGE/Pages/Report.aspx?ItemPath=%2fTraveler%2fTraveler&JobOrder=00002-0000&rs:Command=Render`
as far as I can tell I did everything right.

Comment: What's the paramter that causes the problem ?

Comment: the parameter is JobOrder=00002-0000

Comment: Try to replace the "-" with %2D

Answer (score 0):

Ok I figured it out I needed to get the path from the report server not the report manager so it should look like this `http://crvsql01/ReportServer_MADE2MANAGE/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?%2fTraveler%2fTraveler&JobOrder=00002-0000&rs:Command=Render`